# How to register dynamicaly loaded content (e. g. classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem. When i load external data and i will use jquery events on that data - this is not working because the DOM does not know this. The event-delegation works perfect. I only want to know how to make the `<div class="dialog">    original </div>` loaded from source.txt known to the DOM or another solution to access the external data through the jquery Event. When I use the line `div class="dialog">    original </div>` in the Main document all works fine.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
$( function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width:700,
      height:700,
      show: {
      },
      hide: {
      }
});
$(document).on("click","#link",function(){
 $("#include").load("http://www.damago.de/dev/source.txt"); 
});
$(document).on( "click","#opener", function() {
     $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="include"></div>
        <a id="link" href="#">Include the source.txt with the code</a>
</body>
</html>

source.txt
<div class="dialog">    original </div>
<button id="opener">This is the text of the dialog</button>
```

Comment: So, actually happens when you're running your code? Error messages? Checked the console? My bet is that you'll get a "cross domain"-issue.

Comment: move your dialog creation code inside #opener click event

Comment: Do you mean that way? It does not work. Any suggestions? Thanx in advance
$(document).on( "click","#opener", function() {
$( ".dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width:700,
      height:700,
      show: {
      },
      hide: {
      }
});

Comment: @Karthik Ganesan  The Problem is, that the Content of source.txt (original and This is the text of the Dialog)

<div class="dialog">    original </div>
<button id="opener">This is the text of the dialog</button>

is dynamically createt and so cannot be registered in the main document. Any way to Register it through the source.txt or any other ideas?